# How to cite Usenet’s articles

Tags: bibtex, citing

How can I correctly cite a Usenet’s entry in bibTeX?

I began by doing:

```
 @online{godwinDeclaration,
   Author    = {Mike Godwin},
   url       = {news:1991Aug18.215029.19421@eff.org},
   date      = {1991-8-18},
 }
```

But, I don’t know how to include the groupname `rec.arts.sf-lovers`, have I to use `booktitle`, `journal`, or `chapter` field?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: With most (all?) BibTeX bibliography styles I'm familiar with, the entry type `@online` is not defined, i.e., entries with this type will be treated as being of type `@misc`. The `@misc` type will not do anything with `booktitle`, `journal`, or `chapter` fields. However, you could use that type's `howpublished` and `note` fields to provide any supplemental information you wish.

Comment: Mico, is this have any importance? An information haven’t to be on a special field without worrying about the output? I’ts an offtopic question, but I was also asking if the Usenet’s groupname was necessary if we mention the message url.

Comment: The bibliography style is crucially important: it fully determines all aspects of the formatting of all entries, including which fields are processed to begin with. Hence the question in my initial comment: which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: All right, I use `verbose-trad2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way I find is to use `crossref`

```
@online{godwinDeclaration,
  Title     = {Re: Nazis (was Re: Card’s Article on Homosexuality)},
  Author    = {Mike Godwin},
  url       = {news:1991Aug18.215029.19421@eff.org},
  date      = {1991-8-18},
  crossref  = {USENETsflovers}
}

@online{USENETsflovers,
  url   = {news:rec.arts.sf-lovers}
}
```

But, not all style give an imput to this *hack*.

Comment: How is having *two fields* (after the crossref is resolved) named `url` going to help? Moreover, most BibTeX styles do not recognize a field named `date`; they do, of course. recognize a field named `year`.